# How to execute a command repeatedly with different arguments?

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs, arguments

I'm on Ubuntu. I copied some arguments (separated by newline) and I can use [xsel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility/11927#11927) to print them out like this

```
$ xsel
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
...
```

Now, I want to use each of these arguments for another command and execute that command as many times as there are arguments.

So I tried

```
$ xsel | mycommand "constantArgument" $1
```

However, this executed `mycommand` only for the first argument. How can I execute it for every argument?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the fact that there is more than one argument to mycommand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply use `xargs`

```
xsel | xargs -n1 echo mycommand
```

`-n1` means one arg for mycommand, but it's just dry run, it will show what going to be run, to run it remove `echo`

**For constant Argument**

```
xsel | xargs -I {} -n1 echo mycommand "constantArgument" {}
```

Comment: What if "mycommand" expects more than one argument out of which the xsel contains just one argument?

Comment: `xsel | xargs -n1 echo mycommand  -more-arg`

Comment: `xsel | xargs -n2 echo mycommand` two arg per command

Answer (score 7):

```
xsel | while read line; do mycommand "$line"; done
```

Or something similar. You can also use `xargs`, which is a very powerful command for manipulation of command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For a little customizability:

```
printf "${CMD} %s ${ARG2}\n" `xsel` | sh -n
```

You can remove the *`-noexecute`* flag after you've seen how it works.

If it works for you, you can drop *`sh`* entirely and do this instead:

```
. <<HERE /dev/stdin
    $(printf "${CMD} %s ${ARG2}\n" `xsel`)
HERE
```

Or faster:

```
printf "${CMD} %s ${ARG2}\n" `xsel` | . /dev/stdin
```

Either way is easy and will do it.